# Can I install Ubuntu on Toshiba Satellite Click Mini?

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I'd like to buy a small netebook with long battery life, and found [Toshiba Satellite Click Mini](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/satellite-click-mini/).

I looked at [Ubuntu hardware page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?query=Toshiba%20Satellite%20Click%20Mini&category=Laptop&release=14.04%20LTS&level=Any&vendors=Dellaaaa) but did not find whether this is compatible so appreciate if someone share experience about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "bios does not allow to install Ubuntu"?

Comment: I mean UEFI  that sometimes need heroic procedures to get around and install Ubuntu, as you can see an example here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/How-do-I-install-Linux-Mint-17-from-USB-on-Flex-10/m-p/1597798#M6224

Comment: Nothing is heroic. 64-bit Ubuntu now installs with no problems on UEFI.

Comment: @Pilot6, if you think it is easly, please answer my other question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/625949/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-idealpad-flex-10#

Comment: @karel That question is irrelevant. I'm asking about compatibility of a specific model.

Comment: @wbad When you run the live DVD/USB select *Try Ubuntu without installing* and test the compatibility of your specific model by giving it a test drive from the live DVD/USB.

Comment: @karel please answer in my relevant question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/625949/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-idealpad-flex-10#